# Automatically print emails

Tags: email, printing, thunderbird

I've been looking for a solution for a few days now. I want to print the content of mails from a specific sender immediately. Outlook is not free. And for the current version of Thunderbird, I have not found a plugin.
Does somebody has any idea?

Comment: I'm new. Did I do something wrong? Does nobody have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Solutuion: Thunderbird.
Addons: FiltaQuilla and PrintingTools

There exist a version from FiltaQuilla for Thunderbird 60.